# How do I make the container scoll bar itself instead of extend it using CSS

Tags: html, css

I have two containers in a webpage, one is call header and the other one is called API request data. After getting the data from the backend, if there are much data coming I do not want the whole HTML webpage height being to extend and have the scroll bar. I want the scroll bar in the container itself.

Example:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wDBSY.png)

Comment: try add `max-height`  and `overflow: auto` rules

Answer (score 0):

You may need to set a fix height on the container :

```
div.api_request_data{
  height: 80vh; // for exemple
}
```